# Using 32-bit Lab images in Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, scikit-image

I'm using `skimage` to convert RGB images to Lab colorspace but it seems that skimage uses `float64` datatype while Tensorflow uses `float32`.

Is there any way to convert the 64-bit Lab image to 32-bit datatype? The documentation doesn't cover anything specific about this and I'm not sure if using `image.astype(np.float32)` is the way to go since it might damage the data precision (or not).

Here's a part of the code:

```
from skimage import color, io
import numpy as np    

rgb = io.imread('Test.jpg') # Could be any shape
lab = color.rgb2lab(rgb)

converted = np.array(lab).astype(np.float32)
rgb = color.lab2rgb(converted)
```

The last line gives an error:

```
ValueError: Images of type float must be between -1 and 1.
```

and here's the Stack Trace:

```
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\color\colorconv.py", line 928, in lab2rgb
    return xyz2rgb(lab2xyz(lab))
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\color\colorconv.py", line 855, in lab2xyz
    arr = _prepare_colorarray(lab).copy()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\color\colorconv.py", line 153, in _prepare_colorarray
    return dtype.img_as_float(arr)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\dtype.py", line 291, in img_as_float
    return convert(image, np.float64, force_copy)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\dtype.py", line 195, in convert
    raise ValueError("Images of type float must be between -1 and 1.")
ValueError: Images of type float must be between -1 and 1.
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `x.astype(np.float32)` is perfectly acceptable.  You'll seldom if ever need that level of accuracy.

If you are not careful, however, you may accidentally cast an integer image (e.g., unsigned bytes, going from 0 to 255) into float.  So the safest approach, that will rescale as necessary, is

```
from skimage import img_as_float
image = img_as_float(image).astype(np.float32)
```

Comment: Using `img_as_float(lab).astype(np.float32)` gives me the same error as using `np.array(lab).astype(np.float32)` => `Images of type float must be between -1 and 1.` You could even try the code yourself.

Comment: If you start off with a floating point array that is not between -1 and 1, you may run into this problem.  If you post an example image, or can illustrate your problem on one of the `skimage.data` example images, I'd be glad to take another look.

Answer (score 0):

This was a difficult bug to track down.

If you're using float32 then you get your error as described; however, the error will go away if you use float64 values instead.

Hope that helps! :)

Known bug source:
[Scikit-image Issue](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/2546)